# How to filter cards by user in trello Api?

Tags: node.js, rest, trello

I am trying to filter trello cards by user, I have the users for the board by `/boards/{id}/members` and Im using api `/lists/{id}/cards` to get all cards for a particular list. Do we have a way in trello api where I can add a query parameter to filter the response, such that I get cards which are assigned to particular user/s.

Answer (score 1):

How about using the `/search` API endpoint, using `list:name` and user `@name` query operators?

C.f. [Trello API documentation](https://developers.trello.com/reference#search).

The call would look like (needs proper encoding):

```
/search?query='@jack list:backlog'
```